# I have an empty row with 19 columns. I would like to add to this row sets of two values

Tags: r

My empty row has 19 columns. Starting from column 2 I would like to add value 1 and 2 continously until the last column(19).

For example column 2 is 1, column 3 is 2, column 4 is 1, column 5 is 2, and so on until the end.

I am using R.

When i do dput(mydata) for reference

i get

```
structure(list(column1 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
column2 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column4 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column6 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column8 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column10 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column12 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column14 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column16 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column18 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

i get this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert all columns to the character type at first because it's hard to replace partial elements of a factor object.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
df[1, -1] <- 1:2
df

#   column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10 column11 column12 column13 column14 column15 column16 column17 column18 column19
# 1               1       2       1       2       1       2       1       2        1        2        1        2        1        2        1        2        1        2
```

Note that columns of the result above are all character types. If you want them to back to factors, you need to run the following code:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.factor)
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rep`.

```
dataframe <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=3,ncol=19))
dataframe[1,] <- rep(c(0,1),times=ceiling(ncol(dataframe)/2))[1:ncol(dataframe)]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19
1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: I got this message In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your data with `dput()`?

Comment: structure(list(column1 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column2 = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), column3(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"),

Comment: It keeps repeating until the last column. Every other column is a blank column title.

Comment: Maybe edit your original post so we can see all of the output.

Comment: Sure. i added the full set.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
df[1,] <- c(df[1,1], rep(1:2, ceiling(ncol(df)/2))[seq_len((ncol(df)-1))])
```

or (since you subset anyway):

```
df[1,] <- c(df[1,1], rep(1:2, ncol(df))[seq_len((ncol(df)-1))])
```

Comment: I got In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 2L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated